# Microservices Architecture Best Practice

Tags: spring-boot, go, design-patterns, microservices, centos7

I will be appritiated if anyone answer to below quesion.

How a system will be designed with hundreds of services if each and every service has to be independent with a dedicated port as per microservices architecture? i mean is it a good practice to open hundreds of ports on OS for example?

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? In Spring Cloud you have Spring Gateway where you export only public paths on port 8080 for example.

Comment: I am using Golang to write the services but I will switch to spring boot if I have to...but the main question is how to separate and route the requests to a specific service.

Comment: One example: Use Spring Gateway as a public endpoint. Forward requests to internal microservices based on http requests: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gateway-request-predicates-factories

Comment: it is fine as I have already an API Gateway, do you have any idea about the open ports in microservices architecture?

Comment: No microservice architecture I've ever heard of assumes all the services are on one OS.

Answer (score 1):

1. For security reasons microservices are hosted in private vpc, i.e. the nodes (where the microservices are run) does not have public ip. And the only way to get access to them is via a gateway api (see below). Also "each and every services has to be independent" should be in the means of domain [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/model/domain-analysis) [link2](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).
2. To expose services use the API gateway pattern: "a service that provides a single-entry point for certain groups of microservices" [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern) [link2](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). Note that api gateway is for **a group of microservices**, i.e. there may be several gateways for different groups of services (one for public api, one for mobile api, etc).
3. Only you can answer this question because only you knows what problem you try to solve. Before deciding I recommend to read about [MonolithFirst](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) approach

Comment: actually the story is some clients are getting services from ESB directly from F5 LB and some are getting services from APIGW which is connecting to ESB finally but the company is going to replace the ESB with over 600 services with the next generation of architecture but as per my understanding each service needs to be written independently and come up on its own port , this is the state where is not clear for me that is it a good practice to have over 600 ports up on a single OS?

Comment: As I understand not all of 600 services will be open (actually 600 services is a huge codebase - probably some of them are too fragmented). And even if they will, from the infrastructure perspective you will do something like this: [network] ---> [LB (also maps 'url-to-service')] ---> [VPC (no direct connect to the internet)]. Of course some ports in these nodes (in VPC) will be opened - without it you cannot connect to a service in another node. But it is not a problem in this case, because you are in VPC and only your nodes have direct access.

Comment: around 320 of services are unmapped and can be handled with a single service but almost half of them are mapped and completely different (around 280) with each others so needs to be written as an independent service and come up with different ports, so you believe from design point of view its not ugly and bad design to have this much services each of them on different port, right?

Comment: right, there is nothing wrong with open ports for services as long as you use them and secure them right. Also open ports are open inside a cluster, not outside. I mean that probably for consumers your services will not be provided using ports, but via routes in API GW.

Answer (score -1):

Micro services architecture is somehow the next generation of ESB products but in this case due to the high number of services,I am not sure if it is a solution!